# Import live FX quotes from MT4 to C++

Tags: c++, excel, dde, mql4, mt4

Is there a way to import live data quotes from **`MetaTrader Terminal`** `MT4` to an external C++ program?

Or any possibility to read Excel cells in `C++` via a `DDE` communication?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, there are.

While **`DDE`** is mentioned ( and was heavily used by REUTERS Financial Markets applications for Excel in late 90-s ), I would dare invest a dime into development relying on this technology ( just remember how many projects bled out under surprises that so many `DDE`-calls, working fine since 90-s suddenly started to return **`void // Not-Implemented`** in early 64-bit releases of wV et al ... never more ... ).

---

### How to?

**`MT4`** platform has other options to survive. Live FX Quote-stream could be smart managed by a superior, DLL-based, **`ZeroMQ`** messaging system, available both on the `MetaTrader Terminal` side and on **`C`**, **`C++`**, **`python`**, ... you name 'em all... many other language bindings.

This approach gives you all the control over the architecture and one can setup a truly **distributed processing** as needed.

If are happy with an FX-side using a `MetaTrader Terminal`, you would not miss `aTimeDOMAIN` resolution under a **`1 ms`** treshold inside an **`MQL4`** ecosystem ( but if interested, `ZeroMQ`-code can work down under to some **`25 ns`** ).

Comment: thank you for the information. I also made a research and found client that works without dll, it calls "Named Pipes Client" i guess it works all is required to replicate MSDN client in MQL4 and communicate with central C++ app. Dunno how far i will go but it works fine for some people. @user3666197

Comment: Yes, pipes were recently "built in" into **`New-MQL4.56789`**, however one shall recognise, theirs modus-operandi is O/S dependable ( and thus vulnerability not feasible for our long-term code-base ). While it is also fair to say that `New-MQL4.56789` did changed it's `DLL` interfacing ( one can imagine a nightmare for code-base maintenance once a `string` ceased to be a `string` as it silently started to be a ***hidden*** `struct` ... and we had to redesign all DLL-calls working with `string` params...) **still we consider DLL-mode to be out of MetaQuotes, Inc., control and thus more stable**

Comment: anyway, the `DLL` -based `ZeroMQ` framework can bring you more fruit ... **`python`** + it's smart and ready to use **Excel-reader module** + **`ZeroMQ`** as a process-integration plane towards an open, distributed client/server processing framework with **`C++`**. Isn't that smart enough? Enjoy the powers of `ZeroMQ`. **Worth a time spent on a learning curve.**

Comment: I already have a ready fruit, all i need is to write a code to import data from mt4 or excel DDE and send it back to the meta server, i assume ZeroMQ is perfect for HFT to send orders less than 1ms, but for me right now 300ms also fine. Thank you @user3666197 for the great responses , much appreciated

Comment: i wish i could, need to earn 15 reputation to do that..Sry

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i ranked as promised..:)@user3666197